# Convert bigrams to N-grams in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe

```
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    
sdf = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('first', 'apple edible', '23'),
    ('first', 'edible fruit', '34'),
    ('second', 'flowering plant','11'),
    ('second', 'plant green','7'),
    ('third', 'citrus fruit','16'),
    ('third', 'soft sweet','9'), ],
    ['group', 'bigram', 'count'])

+------+---------------+-----+
|group |bigram         |count|
+------+---------------+-----+
|first |apple edible   |23   |
|first |edible fruit   |34   |
|second|flowering plant|11   |
|second|plant green    |7    |
|third |citrus fruit   |16   |
|third |soft sweet     |9    |
+------+---------------+-----+
```

**I want to collect bigrams into one N-gram(n=3), with the condition:**

1. Bigrams are exactly included in the N-gram;
2. The last word is the same as the beginning;

As a result, the first and second groups are combined into a N-gram, but the third group is not (i want to leave the count column).

```
+------+---------------+-----+---------------------+
|group |bigram         |count|Ngram                |
+------+---------------+-----+---------------------+
|first |apple edible   |23   |apple edible fruit   |
|first |edible fruit   |34   |apple edible fruit   |
|second|flowering plant|11   |flowering plant green|
|second|plant green    |7    |flowering plant green|
+------+---------------+-----+---------------------+
```

So far I have only written the conversion to n-grams, and then I don’t really understand how to further make the condition.

```
sdf_collect = sdf.withColumn('collect_bigram', F.split(F.col("bigram"), " "))\
    .withColumn('collect_bigram', F.regexp_replace('collect_bigram', r'(^\[)|(\]$)', ''))\
    .groupby('group').agg(F.collect_set(F.col('collect_bigram')).alias('collect_bigram'))\

ngram_bigram = NGram(n=3)
ngram_bigram.setInputCol("collect_bigram")
ngram_bigram.setOutputCol("Ngrams")

sdf_ngram3 = ngram_bigram.transform(
    sdf_collect)
```

Comment: What if you have a "fruit apple" and "green flowering"?

Comment: Then instead of the bigrams "edible fruit" and "fruit apple", there will be n-gram: "edible fruit apple". Thus, another n-gram will be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self join can help, the second condition is implemented in the join condition. Then the n-grams are created by combining the arrays of the two sides. When combining the arrays the element that is common in both arrays is omitted:

```python
sdf2 = sdf.withColumn('collect_bigram', F.split(F.col("bigram"), " "))

sdf2.alias("a").join(sdf2.alias("b"), F.expr("a.collect_bigram[1] == b.collect_bigram[0]")) \
    .selectExpr("array_join(array_union(a.collect_bigram, slice(b.collect_bigram, 2, size(b.collect_bigram))), ' ' ) as n")\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Result:

```
+---------------------+
|n                    |
+---------------------+
|flowering plant green|
|apple edible fruit   |
+---------------------+
```

If `fruit apple` is added to the orginal list the result is

```
+---------------------+
|n                    |
+---------------------+
|fruit apple edible   | --> fruit apple + apple edible
|flowering plant green| --> flowering plant + plant green
|edible fruit apple   | --> edible fruit + fruit apple
|citrus fruit apple   | --> citrus fruit + fruit apple
|apple edible fruit   | --> apple edible + edible fruit
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Good answer! I understood how to group pairs of bigrams. But if I want to group more than two bigrams into one n-gram? For example 'apple edible', 'edible fruit', 'fruit round', 'round red'. They are all in the "first" group. The output will then be one n-gram: 'apple edible fruit round red'. Then, as I understand it, you need to group here (by group) and cycle through the columns and connect bigrams in series into one big n-gram? But then I don’t understand how to cut words in a cycle and connect them with the remaining words ...

Comment: You could repeat the process and self-join the result again. But as each time a full cross join is executed, it won't be too fast for n > 3.